# How do i install Linux on windows 8?

Tags: linux

I am currently running on Windows 8 with an Acer S7 laptop. Is there a VM I can use to load Linux directly on to Windows 8? My computer doesn't "boot" when it starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want to boot your PC to see if it works? ... there are couple of options

1. Use windows 8 recovery disk
2. Use Linux live CD, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD which will allow you to
   boot the PC and browse file system